# apt-get Cannot resolve unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies, ros

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, 64-bit version. My system refuses to let me install, remove or repair any package.

I just recently tried to install ROS Jade via the instructions give on the site [here](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Ubuntu). Ever since then, the output I get from `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` is as shown below:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgazebo5-dev : Depends: libavformat-dev but it is not installed
                  Depends: libavcodec-dev but it is not installed
                  Depends: libswscale-dev but it is not installed
 libopencv-highgui-dev : Depends: libavcodec-dev (>= 0.svn20080206) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libavformat-dev but it is not installed
                         Depends: libswscale-dev but it is not installed
 libvtk5-dev : Depends: libavformat-dev but it is not installed
               Depends: libavutil-dev but it is not installed
               Depends: libavcodec-dev but it is not installed
               Depends: libswscale-dev but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

When I try to run `sudo apt-get -f install`, I get this output:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  collada-dom-dev collada-dom2.4-dp-base collada-dom2.4-dp-dev docutils-common
  docutils-doc firefox-locale-th freeglut3 freeglut3-dev gazebo5
  gazebo5-common gazebo5-plugin-base hddtemp hdf5-helpers libapr1-dev
  libaprutil1-dev libarmadillo4 libarpack2 libassimp-dev libassimp3
  libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavutil-dev libcf0 libconsole-bridge-dev
  libconsole-bridge0.2 libcv-dev libcvaux-dev libdap-dev libdap11
  libdapclient3 libdapserver7 libeigen3-dev libepsilon1 libflann-dev
  libflann1.8 libfltk1.1 libfltk1.1-dev libfreeimage-dev libfreeimage3
  libfreexl1 libgazebo5 libgazebo5-dev libgdal-dev libgdal1h libgeos-3.4.2
  libgeos-c1 libgeos-dev libgif-dev libgl2ps-dev libgl2ps0 libgtest-dev
  libgtkglext1 libgts-0.7-5 libgts-bin libgts-dev libhdf4-0-alt
  libhdf4-alt-dev libhdf5-7 libhdf5-dev libhighgui-dev libkml0 liblog4cxx10
  liblog4cxx10-dev liblz4-1 liblz4-dev libnetcdf-dev libnetcdfc++4 libnetcdfc7
  libnetcdff5 libntdb1 libogdi3.2 libogre-1.8-dev libogre-1.8.0
  libopencv-calib3d-dev libopencv-calib3d2.4 libopencv-contrib-dev
  libopencv-contrib2.4 libopencv-core-dev libopencv-core2.4 libopencv-dev
  libopencv-features2d-dev libopencv-features2d2.4 libopencv-flann-dev
  libopencv-flann2.4 libopencv-gpu-dev libopencv-gpu2.4 libopencv-highgui-dev
  libopencv-highgui2.4 libopencv-imgproc-dev libopencv-imgproc2.4
  libopencv-legacy-dev libopencv-legacy2.4 libopencv-ml-dev libopencv-ml2.4
  libopencv-objdetect-dev libopencv-objdetect2.4 libopencv-ocl-dev
  libopencv-ocl2.4 libopencv-photo-dev libopencv-photo2.4
  libopencv-stitching-dev libopencv-stitching2.4 libopencv-superres-dev
  libopencv-superres2.4 libopencv-ts-dev libopencv-ts2.4 libopencv-video-dev
  libopencv-video2.4 libopencv-videostab-dev libopencv-videostab2.4
  libopencv2.4-java libopencv2.4-jni libopenni-dev
  libopenni-sensor-pointclouds0 libopenni0 libpcl-1.7-all libpcl-1.7-all-dev
  libpcl-1.7-bin libpcl-1.7-doc libpcl-apps-1.7 libpcl-apps-1.7-dev
  libpcl-common-1.7 libpcl-common-1.7-dev libpcl-features-1.7
  libpcl-features-1.7-dev libpcl-filters-1.7 libpcl-filters-1.7-dev
  libpcl-geometry-1.7-dev libpcl-io-1.7 libpcl-io-1.7-dev libpcl-kdtree-1.7
  libpcl-kdtree-1.7-dev libpcl-keypoints-1.7 libpcl-keypoints-1.7-dev
  libpcl-octree-1.7 libpcl-octree-1.7-dev libpcl-outofcore-1.7
  libpcl-outofcore-1.7-dev libpcl-people-1.7 libpcl-people-1.7-dev
  libpcl-recognition-1.7 libpcl-recognition-1.7-dev libpcl-registration-1.7
  libpcl-registration-1.7-dev libpcl-sample-consensus-1.7
  libpcl-sample-consensus-1.7-dev libpcl-search-1.7 libpcl-search-1.7-dev
  libpcl-segmentation-1.7 libpcl-segmentation-1.7-dev libpcl-surface-1.7
  libpcl-surface-1.7-dev libpcl-tracking-1.7 libpcl-tracking-1.7-dev
  libpcl-visualization-1.7 libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev libphonon4
  libplayerc++3.0 libplayerc++3.0-dev libplayerc3.0 libplayerc3.0-dev
  libplayercommon3.0 libplayercommon3.0-dev libplayercore3.0
  libplayercore3.0-dev libplayerdrivers3.0 libplayerdrivers3.0-dev
  libplayerinterface3.0 libplayerinterface3.0-dev libplayerjpeg3.0
  libplayerjpeg3.0-dev libplayertcp3.0 libplayertcp3.0-dev libplayerwkb3.0
  libplayerwkb3.0-dev libpoco-dev libpococrypto9 libpocodata9
  libpocofoundation9 libpocomysql9 libpoconet9 libpoconetssl9 libpocoodbc9
  libpocosqlite9 libpocoutil9 libpocoxml9 libpocozip9 libproj0 libprotoc-dev
  libprotoc8 libpyside-dev libpyside-py3-1.2 libpyside1.2 libqhull-dev
  libqhull6 libqwt-dev libqwt5-qt4 libqwt6 libruby1.9.1 libsctp-dev
  libsdformat2 libsdformat2-dev libshiboken-dev libshiboken-py3-1.2
  libshiboken1.2 libsimbody-dev libsimbody3.5 libspatialite-dev libspatialite5
  libspnav0 libstatgrab9 libswscale-dev libtar-dev libtinyxml-dev
  liburdfdom-dev liburdfdom-headers-dev liburdfdom-model-state0.2
  liburdfdom-model0.2 liburdfdom-sensor0.2 liburdfdom-tools
  liburdfdom-world0.2 liburiparser1 libusb-1.0-0-dev libusb-1.0-doc
  libvo-amrwbenc0 libvtk-java libvtk5-dev libvtk5-qt4-dev libvtk5.8
  libvtk5.8-qt4 libwebp-dev libwebpdemux1 libxaw7-dev libxerces-c-dev
  libxerces-c3.1 libxmu-dev libxmu-headers libxpm-dev libxss-dev libyaml-0-2
  libyaml-cpp-dev libyaml-cpp0.5 libzzip-0-13 libzzip-dev opencv-data
  openni-utils phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer phonon-backend-gstreamer-common
  phonon-backend-gstreamer1.0 proj-bin proj-data python-catkin-pkg
  python-catkin-pkg-modules python-docutils python-empy python-netifaces
  python-ntdb python-opencv python-opengl python-psutil python-pycurl
  python-pydot python-pygments python-pyside python-pyside.phonon
  python-pyside.qtcore python-pyside.qtdeclarative python-pyside.qtgui
  python-pyside.qthelp python-pyside.qtnetwork python-pyside.qtopengl
  python-pyside.qtscript python-pyside.qtsql python-pyside.qtsvg
  python-pyside.qttest python-pyside.qtuitools python-pyside.qtwebkit
  python-pyside.qtxml python-qt4-dev python-qt4-gl python-qwt5-qt4
  python-roman python-rosdep python-rosdistro python-rosdistro-modules
  python-rospkg python-rospkg-modules python-sip-dev python-urlgrabber
  python-vtk python-yaml robot-player-dev ros-jade-actionlib
  ros-jade-actionlib-msgs ros-jade-actionlib-tutorials ros-jade-angles
  ros-jade-bond ros-jade-bond-core ros-jade-bondcpp ros-jade-bondpy
  ros-jade-camera-calibration ros-jade-camera-calibration-parsers
  ros-jade-camera-info-manager ros-jade-catkin ros-jade-class-loader
  ros-jade-cmake-modules ros-jade-collada-parser ros-jade-collada-urdf
  ros-jade-common-msgs ros-jade-common-tutorials
  ros-jade-compressed-depth-image-transport
  ros-jade-compressed-image-transport ros-jade-control-msgs
  ros-jade-control-toolbox ros-jade-controller-interface
  ros-jade-controller-manager ros-jade-controller-manager-msgs
  ros-jade-cpp-common ros-jade-cv-bridge ros-jade-depth-image-proc
  ros-jade-diagnostic-aggregator ros-jade-diagnostic-analysis
  ros-jade-diagnostic-common-diagnostics ros-jade-diagnostic-msgs
  ros-jade-diagnostic-updater ros-jade-diagnostics
  ros-jade-dynamic-reconfigure ros-jade-eigen-conversions
  ros-jade-eigen-stl-containers ros-jade-executive-smach ros-jade-filters
  ros-jade-gencpp ros-jade-geneus ros-jade-genlisp ros-jade-genmsg
  ros-jade-genpy ros-jade-geometric-shapes ros-jade-geometry
  ros-jade-geometry-msgs ros-jade-geometry-tutorials
  ros-jade-hardware-interface ros-jade-image-geometry ros-jade-image-transport
  ros-jade-joint-state-publisher ros-jade-kdl-conversions ros-jade-kdl-parser
  ros-jade-message-filters ros-jade-message-generation
  ros-jade-message-runtime ros-jade-mk ros-jade-nav-msgs ros-jade-nodelet
  ros-jade-nodelet-core ros-jade-nodelet-topic-tools
  ros-jade-nodelet-tutorial-math ros-jade-octomap ros-jade-orocos-kdl
  ros-jade-pluginlib ros-jade-pluginlib-tutorials ros-jade-python-orocos-kdl
  ros-jade-random-numbers ros-jade-realtime-tools ros-jade-resource-retriever
  ros-jade-robot ros-jade-robot-model ros-jade-robot-state-publisher
  ros-jade-ros ros-jade-ros-base ros-jade-ros-comm ros-jade-ros-core
  ros-jade-ros-tutorials ros-jade-rosbag ros-jade-rosbag-migration-rule
  ros-jade-rosbag-storage ros-jade-rosbash ros-jade-rosboost-cfg
  ros-jade-rosbuild ros-jade-rosclean ros-jade-rosconsole
  ros-jade-rosconsole-bridge ros-jade-roscpp ros-jade-roscpp-core
  ros-jade-roscpp-serialization ros-jade-roscpp-traits
  ros-jade-roscpp-tutorials ros-jade-roscreate ros-jade-rosgraph
  ros-jade-rosgraph-msgs ros-jade-roslang ros-jade-roslaunch ros-jade-roslib
  ros-jade-roslisp ros-jade-roslz4 ros-jade-rosmake ros-jade-rosmaster
  ros-jade-rosmsg ros-jade-rosnode ros-jade-rosout ros-jade-rospack
  ros-jade-rosparam ros-jade-rospy ros-jade-rospy-tutorials
  ros-jade-rosservice ros-jade-rostest ros-jade-rostime ros-jade-rostopic
  ros-jade-rosunit ros-jade-roswtf ros-jade-self-test ros-jade-sensor-msgs
  ros-jade-shape-msgs ros-jade-smach ros-jade-smach-msgs ros-jade-smach-ros
  ros-jade-smclib ros-jade-std-msgs ros-jade-std-srvs ros-jade-stereo-msgs
  ros-jade-tf ros-jade-tf-conversions ros-jade-tf2 ros-jade-tf2-kdl
  ros-jade-tf2-msgs ros-jade-tf2-py ros-jade-tf2-ros ros-jade-topic-tools
  ros-jade-trajectory-msgs ros-jade-turtle-actionlib ros-jade-turtle-tf
  ros-jade-turtle-tf2 ros-jade-turtlesim ros-jade-urdf
  ros-jade-urdf-parser-plugin ros-jade-visualization-msgs ros-jade-xacro
  ros-jade-xmlrpcpp ruby ruby1.9.1 sbcl sdformat-sdf shiboken
  simplescreenrecorder-lib sip-dev tango-icon-theme tcl-vtk tcl8.6-dev
  tk8.6-dev uuid-dev x11proto-scrnsaver-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavutil-dev libswscale-dev
Suggested packages:
  libgsm1-dev libschroedinger-dev libspeex-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavutil-dev libswscale-dev
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 298 not upgraded.
30 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 3,386 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe libavutil-dev amd64 6:9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [111 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe libavcodec-dev amd64 6:9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [2,605 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe libavformat-dev amd64 6:9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [576 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe libswscale-dev amd64 6:9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [94.0 kB]
Fetched 3,386 kB in 14s (236 kB/s)                                             
(Reading database ... 250238 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libavutil-dev_6%3a9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libavutil-dev (6:9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libavutil-dev_6%3a9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/libavutil/lfg.h', which is also in package ffmpeg 2.6.7~trusty1.23
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../libavcodec-dev_6%3a9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libavcodec-dev (6:9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libavcodec-dev_6%3a9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/libavcodec/vdpau.h', which is also in package ffmpeg 2.6.7~trusty1.23
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../libavformat-dev_6%3a9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libavformat-dev (6:9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libavformat-dev_6%3a9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/libavformat/version.h', which is also in package ffmpeg 2.6.7~trusty1.23
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../libswscale-dev_6%3a9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libswscale-dev (6:9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libswscale-dev_6%3a9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/libswscale/swscale.h', which is also in package ffmpeg 2.6.7~trusty1.23
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libavutil-dev_6%3a9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libavcodec-dev_6%3a9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libavformat-dev_6%3a9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libswscale-dev_6%3a9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

For some reason, it marks all the ROS libraries as well as most of their dependencies as unused dependencies. And why is there an error with overwriting those system files?

If I try `sudo apt-get autoremove`, I just get the same output as the first case.

I've tried using `sudo apt-get clean` followed by `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, but it gets the same result.

The output from trying `sudo dpkg --configure -a` is:

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libvtk5-dev:
 libvtk5-dev depends on libavformat-dev; however:
  Package libavformat-dev is not installed.
 libvtk5-dev depends on libavutil-dev; however:
  Package libavutil-dev is not installed.
 libvtk5-dev depends on libavcodec-dev; however:
  Package libavcodec-dev is not installed.
 libvtk5-dev depends on libswscale-dev; however:
  Package libswscale-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libvtk5-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libvtk5-qt4-dev:
 libvtk5-qt4-dev depends on libvtk5-dev (= 5.8.0-14.1ubuntu3); however:
  Package libvtk5-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libvtk5-qt4-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpcl-people-1.7-dev:
 libpcl-people-1.7-dev depends on libvtk5-dev; however:
  Package libvtk5-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpcl-people-1.7-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libopencv-highgui-dev:amd64:
 libopencv-highgui-dev:amd64 depends on libavcodec-dev (>= 0.svn20080206); however:
  Package libavcodec-dev is not installed.
 libopencv-highgui-dev:amd64 depends on libavformat-dev; however:
  Package libavformat-dev is not installed.
 libopencv-highgui-dev:amd64 depends on libswscale-dev; however:
  Package libswscale-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libopencv-highgui-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libopencv-contrib-dev:amd64:
 libopencv-contrib-dev:amd64 depends on libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package libopencv-highgui-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libopencv-contrib-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcvaux-dev:amd64:
 libcvaux-dev:amd64 depends on libopencv-contrib-dev; however:
  Package libopencv-contrib-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcvaux-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev:
 libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev depends on libvtk5-dev; however:
  Package libvtk5-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libopencv-videostab-dev:amd64:
 libopencv-videostab-dev:amd64 depends on libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package libopencv-highgui-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libopencv-videostab-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgazebo5-dev:amd64:
 libgazebo5-dev:amd64 depends on libavformat-dev; however:
  Package libavformat-dev is not installed.
 libgazebo5-dev:amd64 depends on libavcodec-dev; however:
  Package libavcodec-dev is not installed.
 libgazebo5-dev:amd64 depends on libswscale-dev; however:
  Package libswscale-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libgazebo5-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libopencv-dev:
 libopencv-dev depends on libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package libopencv-highgui-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libopencv-dev depends on libopencv-contrib-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package libopencv-contrib-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libopencv-dev depends on libopencv-videostab-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package libopencv-videostab-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libopencv-dev depends on libcvaux-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package libcvaux-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libopencv-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpcl-io-1.7-dev:
 libpcl-io-1.7-dev depends on libvtk5-dev; however:
  Package libvtk5-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpcl-io-1.7-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libopencv-legacy-dev:amd64:
 libopencv-legacy-dev:amd64 depends on libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package libopencv-highgui-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libopencv-legacy-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpcl-recognition-1.7-dev:
 libpcl-recognition-1.7-dev depends on libpcl-io-1.7-dev; however:
  Package libpcl-io-1.7-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpcl-recognition-1.7-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ros-jade-cv-bridge:
 ros-jade-cv-bridge depends on libopencv-dev; however:
  Package libopencv-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ros-jade-cv-bridge (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpcl-1.7-all-dev:
 libpcl-1.7-all-dev depends on libpcl-io-1.7-dev; however:
  Package libpcl-io-1.7-dev is not configured yet.
 libpcl-1.7-all-dev depends on libpcl-people-1.7-dev; however:
  Package libpcl-people-1.7-dev is not configured yet.
 libpcl-1.7-all-dev depends on libpcl-recognition-1.7-dev; however:
  Package libpcl-recognition-1.7-dev is not configured yet.
 libpcl-1.7-all-dev depends on libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev; however:
  Package libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpcl-1.7-all-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libopencv-objdetect-dev:amd64:
 libopencv-objdetect-dev:amd64 depends on libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package libopencv-highgui-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libopencv-objdetect-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ros-jade-compressed-image-transport:
 ros-jade-compressed-image-transport depends on ros-jade-cv-bridge; however:
  Package ros-jade-cv-bridge is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ros-jade-compressed-image-transport (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libopencv-ocl-dev:amd64:
 libopencv-ocl-dev:amd64 depends on libopencv-objdetect-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package libopencv-objdetect-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libopencv-ocl-dev:amd64 depends on libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package libopencv-highgui-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libopencv-ocl-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpcl-apps-1.7-dev:
 libpcl-apps-1.7-dev depends on libpcl-io-1.7-dev; however:
  Package libpcl-io-1.7-dev is not configured yet.
 libpcl-apps-1.7-dev depends on libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev; however:
  Package libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev is not configured yet.
 libpcl-apps-1.7-dev depends on libpcl-recognition-1.7-dev; however:
  Package libpcl-recognition-1.7-dev is not configured yet.
 libpcl-apps-1.7-dev depends on libvtk5-qt4-dev; however:
  Package libvtk5-qt4-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpcl-apps-1.7-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ros-jade-image-geometry:
 ros-jade-image-geometry depends on libopencv-dev; however:
  Package libopencv-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ros-jade-image-geometry (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libopencv-superres-dev:amd64:
 libopencv-superres-dev:amd64 depends on libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1); however:
  Package libopencv-highgui-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libopencv-superres-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpcl-1.7-all:
 libpcl-1.7-all depends on libpcl-1.7-all-dev; however:
  Package libpcl-1.7-all-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpcl-1.7-all (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libplayerdrivers3.0-dev:
 libplayerdrivers3.0-dev depends on libcvaux-dev; however:
  Package libcvaux-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libplayerdrivers3.0-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libhighgui-dev:amd64:
 libhighgui-dev:amd64 depends on libopencv-highgui-dev; however:
  Package libopencv-highgui-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libhighgui-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ros-jade-camera-calibration:
 ros-jade-camera-calibration depends on ros-jade-cv-bridge; however:
  Package ros-jade-cv-bridge is not configured yet.
 ros-jade-camera-calibration depends on ros-jade-image-geometry; however:
  Package ros-jade-image-geometry is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ros-jade-camera-calibration (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpcl-outofcore-1.7-dev:
 libpcl-outofcore-1.7-dev depends on libpcl-io-1.7-dev; however:
  Package libpcl-io-1.7-dev is not configured yet.
 libpcl-outofcore-1.7-dev depends on libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev; however:
  Package libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpcl-outofcore-1.7-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ros-jade-depth-image-proc:
 ros-jade-depth-image-proc depends on ros-jade-cv-bridge; however:
  Package ros-jade-cv-bridge is not configured yet.
 ros-jade-depth-image-proc depends on ros-jade-image-geometry; however:
  Package ros-jade-image-geometry is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ros-jade-depth-image-proc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcv-dev:amd64:
 libcv-dev:amd64 depends on libopencv-objdetect-dev; however:
  Package libopencv-objdetect-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libcv-dev:amd64 depends on libopencv-legacy-dev; however:
  Package libopencv-legacy-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libcv-dev:amd64 depends on libopencv-ocl-dev; however:
  Package libopencv-ocl-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcv-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ros-jade-compressed-depth-image-transport:
 ros-jade-compressed-depth-image-transport depends on ros-jade-cv-bridge; however:
  Package ros-jade-cv-bridge is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ros-jade-compressed-depth-image-transport (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of robot-player-dev:
 robot-player-dev depends on libplayerdrivers3.0-dev (>= 3.0.2+dfsg-4.1ubuntu3); however:
  Package libplayerdrivers3.0-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package robot-player-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libvtk5-dev
 libvtk5-qt4-dev
 libpcl-people-1.7-dev
 libopencv-highgui-dev:amd64
 libopencv-contrib-dev:amd64
 libcvaux-dev:amd64
 libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev
 libopencv-videostab-dev:amd64
 libgazebo5-dev:amd64
 libopencv-dev
 libpcl-io-1.7-dev
 libopencv-legacy-dev:amd64
 libpcl-recognition-1.7-dev
 ros-jade-cv-bridge
 libpcl-1.7-all-dev
 libopencv-objdetect-dev:amd64
 ros-jade-compressed-image-transport
 libopencv-ocl-dev:amd64
 libpcl-apps-1.7-dev
 ros-jade-image-geometry
 libopencv-superres-dev:amd64
 libpcl-1.7-all
 libplayerdrivers3.0-dev
 libhighgui-dev:amd64
 ros-jade-camera-calibration
 libpcl-outofcore-1.7-dev
 ros-jade-depth-image-proc
 libcv-dev:amd64
 ros-jade-compressed-depth-image-transport
 robot-player-dev
```

Comment: I suspect the crucial line is "30 not fully installed or removed." as you pr'ly know. I have found the approach described by  shankar in post 3  here  https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2264110&p=13222580#post13222580 to be the only way to get out of that kind of trap consistently.  As he says, it is risky and you need to be careful. Other approaches, probably less risky are described in earlier posts in that thread. Tedious work for 30 packages. Maybe try something easier first.

Comment: You seem to have unwisely added a non-Ubuntu source that provides software *incompatible* with your Ubuntu system. It cannot be 'fixed'. You must uninstall ALL packages from that source, and delete the source, to restore a functioning package manager. It will not fix itself. While broken, you are not receiving security upgrades.